# Generic MongoRepository Interface for Multiple Documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is an example on accessing Person Document from MongoDB.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>
 @Query("{ 'firstname' : ?0 }")
 List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);
}
```

If I have 5 documents ex: Person, Family, Relation. etc.
Do I need to create 5 Repositories and Extend MongoRepository or is there a way to achieve in one MongoRepository.

Comment: can anyone chime in !